# Migrating multiple User DSN connections (ODBC)

Tags: windows, database, migration, odbc, dsn

I'm looking for a way to migrate multiple User DSN connections (ODBC) from an old server to a fresh new server.

In the registry i can only see the saved User DSN connections of my own user, is there a way for me to export the User DSN Connections of all users (15 in total) so they wont have to manually set up their DSN connections on the new server?

Thanks!

Best Regards

Comment: If you are in an Active Directory environment, I recommend using Group Policy Preferences to manage DSNs.

Comment: @M. St. did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

if drivers are installed, you could use the following PowerShell Script:

```
$OldDsn = Invoke-Command -ComputerName OldServer { get-odbcdsn } | % { 
    $splat = @{}
    if ($_.PropertyValue) { $splat['SetPropertyValue'] = $_.PropertyValue }
    Add-OdbcDsn -Name $_.Name -DsnType $_.DsnType -Platform $_.Platform `
                -DriverName $_.DriverName @splat
}
```

Run this on the new server in an elevated PowerShell / ISE and change the ComputerName Parameter of `Invoke-Command` to your old servers hostname

Answer (score 0):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\
```

The file c:\windows\odbc.ini also duplicates some of the information.

The C:\Windows\ODBCINST.INI has the driver information only.

**This is NOT A SUBSTITUE for actually installing the drivers!**

There are cooresponding registry keys for ODBCINST.INI in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\
```